# Order of a sixth root in group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

This question originates from Chapter 10, H3 of the 2nd edition of [A Book of Abstract Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486474178) by Charles C. Pinter.

> Let $a$ denote an element of a group $G$.  Let $a$ have order 10.  If $a$ has a sixth root in $G$, say $a=b^6$, what is the order of $b$?

Here is what I think:

> Given $\operatorname{ord}(a) = 10$ and $a=b^6$,
>
> $\qquad a^{10} = e = (b^{6})^{10} = b^{60}$
>
> Let $\operatorname{ord}(b) = x, x$ must divide $60 \implies x\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60\}.$
>
> - $x=1: b = e = b^6 = a$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 1.$
> - $x=2: b^2 = e = b^6 = a$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 1.$
> - $x=3: b^3 = e = b^6 = a$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 1.$
> - $x=4: b^4 = e = b^{12} = a^2$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 2.$
> - $x=5: b^5 = e = b^{30} = a^5$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 5.$
> - $x=6: b^6 = e = a$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 1.$
> - $x=10: b^{10} = e = b^{30} = a^5$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 5.$
> - $x=12: b^{12} = e = a^2$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 2.$
> - $x=15: b^{15} = e = b^{30} = a^5$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 5.$
> - $x=20: b^{20} = e = b^{60} = a^{10}$.
> - $x=30: b^{30} = e = a^5$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a) \ne 5.$
> - $x=60: b^{60} = e = a^{10}.$
>
> Hence $x \in \{20,60\}$.

So it seems $x=20$ as $20 < 60$.

Or is there a way to rule out $20$?

Comment: You start well with the observation that $b^{60}=e$ and therefore the order of $b$ divides $60$.  While some divisors can be ruled out (e.g. $b$ cannot have order dividing six), there doesn't seem to be enough information to uniquely determine the order of $b$.  Is it possible some extra data is given or that the problem is to find the smallest possible order for $b$?

Comment: Why did you stop at $20$? It's entirely possible that the order is $60$.

Comment: @hardmath, per definition in the book on page 105: **Definition.** _If there exists a nonzero integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$, then the order of the element $a$ is defined to be the least positive integer $n$ such that $a^n=e.$_

Comment: @MattSamuel, that's because the order is the least positive integer $x$ such that $b^x = e$, and $20 < 60$.

Comment: But you haven't proven that $b^{20}=e$, only that this method doesn't rule it out. In a cyclic group of order $60$, we can have that $60$ is the smallest power that is the identity, not $20$.

Comment: I see your points, and have edited the original posting.

Comment: @MattSamuel gave an example where the order of $b$ is $60$, not $20$

Comment: In the cyclic group of order $20$ generated by $x$, $a=x^6$ has order $10$, so $20$ is also possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} o(b^6) & = \frac {o(b)} {\text {gcd}\ (o(b),6)}. \\ \implies o(b) & = 10 \cdot \text {gcd}\ (o(b),6). \\ \implies o(b) & = 10 \cdot \text {gcd}\ (10 \cdot \text {gcd}\ (o(b),6),6). \\ \implies o(b) & = 20 \cdot \text {gcd} (5 \cdot \text {gcd}\ (o(b),6) , 3). \\ \end{align}$$

Now if $3 \nmid o(b)$ then we have $o(b)=20.$ Otherwise if $3 \mid o(b)$ we have $o(b) = 60.$ So $o(b) = 20\ \text {or}\ 60.$

Observe that both the options are equally valid. Because for $n=20,60$ consider a generator $b$ of $\Bbb Z_n.$  Observe that $a=b^6$ has the same property as mentioned in the question. But for the first case we have $o(b)=20$ and for the second case we have $o(b)=60.$

Answer (score 0):

Just realize in general

> If $a$ has order $n$ and $a$ has a $k$th root $b$, then $b$ has order
>   $\displaystyle\frac{nk}{l}$, where $n$ and $l$ are relatively prime.

Applying this to my original question where $n=10, k=6$.  So

$\qquad\displaystyle\operatorname{ord}(b) = \frac{10\cdot 6}{l}\qquad$ where $10$ and $l$ are relatively prime.
$\implies l \in \{1,3,7,9\}$

- $\displaystyle l=1: \operatorname{ord}(b) = \frac{60}{1} = 60$
- $\displaystyle l=3: \operatorname{ord}(b) = \frac{60}{3} = 20$
- $\displaystyle l=7: \operatorname{ord}(b) = \frac{60}{7}$ (not possible since it's not an integer)
- $\displaystyle l=9: \operatorname{ord}(b) = \frac{60}{9}$  (not possible since it's not an integer)

Hence $b$ has order of either $20$ or $60$.

$\Box$